Is a series of religious (Christian) writings read and meditated on for growth a 'devotion' or a 'devotional'?
Both 'devotion' and 'devotional' are commonly used in Christian language and writings. Which is correct?
I've examined my current dictionary and found 'devotional' is not listed. Looking at a much older dictionary I have (c. 1900), I found both listed, but 'devotional' only as an adjective.
Usage seems to be in favour of 'devotion', judging by Google Ngram. So overall it appears 'devotion' may be correct, but 'devotional' is extremely frequently used also (one quick example from a Google search).
Which is correct as a noun?

Collins dictionary has "devotional" as a noun, meaning a short religious or prayer service. See https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/devotional

"Both 'devotion' and 'devotional' are commonly used in Christian language and writings. Which is correct?" In what context? -- " judging by Google Ngram" Please have a look at the examples.

The term for Christian literature used in the way you describe is "devotional".
This is a standard category in Christian bookshops. For example:

Devotionals section on Olive Tree
Lent Devotionals Bundle from Accordance
Lexham Press Devotionals Bundle from Logos

However, "devotions" is also used in individual titles:

Devotions on the Greek New Testament from Accordance
One Minute Devotions Grace for Today from Amazon

Dictionaries define the terms by reference to religious services rather than specifically to the literature:

"devotional - noun 3. Often devotionals. a short religious service" (dictionary.com)
"devotion - noun 4. Often devotions. Ecclesiastical. religious observance or worship; a form of prayer or worship for special use." (dictionary.com)

I am familiar with the terms and have used them in Christian contexts in Australia for many years.
In my experience, the substantive "devotional" refers to the literature, perhaps as nominalisation of the adjective "devotional literature -> devotional". The term "devotions" (as plurale tantum) refers primarily to the discussion of a Bible text for Christian edification, regardless of whether the commentary is taken from a published volume. The use of "devotions" to refer to the volume itself can be considered to be metonymy or semantic broadening.
To answer your question: it is standard bookstore usage for the published material to be called devotionals. You can read from a devotional during devotions, and each 'chapter', if intended to be read during devotions, can itself be called devotions. So you might have a single devotional (volume) containing multiple devotions (chapters).
Disclaimer: I have picked links to (major) online stores that sell books because the stores can be regarded as usage authorities regarding words used to categorise books. At the time of submitting this answer, I don't have an affiliate relationship with any of the linked bookstores, and I do not expect any direct financial reward from click-throughs or purchases using the links I supplied.

Yes; OP is right. There is a missing sense in most of the usually reliable dictionaries.  How to Write a Devotional: The Ultimate Guide by
Jerry Jenkins; I am looking to buy a good Devotional and I was going to see what you recommend ... I also grew up on Chambers' My Utmost for His Highest; and ...

" 'My Daily Pursuit: Devotions for Every Day by A.W. Tozer': A good devotional, thought-provoking and challenging. I would consider it to be good reading for professing Christians. {Goodreads}" show typical obviously hard-copy usages.
